# Flink Error - Connection Unexpectedly closed by remote task manager

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I'm writing a streaming application with Flink and getting this error from Flink -

> org.apache.flink.runtime.io.network.exception.RemoteTransportException
> : Connection Unexpectedly closed by remote task manager
> xx1.xx2.xx3.xx4:abcd. This might indicate the that the remote task
> manager was lost.

The configurations for Flink are as follows

```
    flink.parallelism.default = 60
    flink.taskmanager.numberOfTaskSlots = 3
    flink.taskmanager.memory.flink.size = 1G
    flink.jobmanager.memory.jvm-metaspace.size = 512mb
    flink.taskmanager.memory.jvm-metaspace.size = 2048mb
```

Could see the below error from Job manager

```
[WARN  ] [flink-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-1504] akka.remote.ReliableDeliverySupervisor event.slf4j.Slf4jLogger$$anonfun$receive$1.$anonfun$applyOrElse$2(Slf4jLogger.scala:77) Association with remote system [akka.tcp://flink@aa.bb.cc.dd:xyz] has failed, address is now gated for [50] ms. Reason: [Association failed with [akka.tcp://flink@aa.bb.cc.dd:xyz]] Caused by: [java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: /aa.bb.cc.dd:xyz]

[ERROR ] [flink-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-1504] handler.job.JobDetailsHandler rest.handler.AbstractHandler.handleException(AbstractHandler.java:200) Exception occurred in REST handler: Job jdujdujduldi24kcufu48jc not found
```

Could you please help me with, what is the cause for the error and how to resolve it.

Comment: can you ping the tasks managers? can you access the Task Managers from the Job Manager machines using ssh without passwarod? are you using flink stand-alone cluster?

Comment: What do you see in the logs of the task manager that become unavailable? Also, the memory sizes you've set seem a bit odd. The default for `taskmanager.memory.flink.size` is 1280mb; I'm not sure it will work to go as small as 1G. And on the other hand, 2048mb for `taskmanager.memory.jvm-metaspace.size` is rather enormous.

Comment: Also, what version of Flink is this?

Comment: Hi David, Flink version is 1.10.0. Tried to increase the taskmanager.memory.flink.size to 3G also

Comment: Is something progressing before the errorl? It almost looks like the jobmanager cannot reach the taskmanager at all. In this case, make sure you can connect from each node to all other nodes.